# Client saying Another freelancer did the job while on contract

Tags: contract-cancellation

Recently, I got an offer to make a web page for a company on Upwork, The client and I agreed on 10 days to finish the job and I accepted the offer and started working on the application.

7 days after the contract started the client sent me a message telling me that another freelancer did the job and he/she no longer needs me.

> Hello. One of the freelancers that wanted to do this job did the work at risk, and actually did the Dashboard for this Request as I require it 
>   Effectively I no longer need this job done and wish to cancel the contract
>   My Apologies for this

I consider this to be so unprofessional. How do I respond to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Upwork, I think there should be a valid contract between client and freelancer, the client should have made a deposit for the job, so you can:

1. finish the work and pretend the payment, ignoring what he says
2. ask maybe a 50%-75% of the final cost as indemnification for the work you did already

In case 1, I think you can contact Upwork support because the client does not respect the contract.